# MYSQL LEFT JOIN and multiple ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I need to join 2 tables.

In the first table (geoname) there is a list of city codes, country codes and area codes.
In the second table (alternatename) there is a list of available translations for each city code.

The sqlfiddle example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7df393/1

What I need is: give me an ordered list of cities by name, taking the italian language version if available or the english if it is not available or the NULL language if previous are not available. For each language, take the preferred version if available.

I tried with many queries, but I don't get the expected result. This is the last one:

```
SELECT g.geonameid, name 
FROM geoname g 
LEFT JOIN alternatename a ON g.geonameid = a.geonameid AND 
  (a.lang = 'it' OR a.lang = 'en' OR a.lang = NULL) 
WHERE name IS NOT NULL and fcode="PPL"
GROUP BY g.geonameid 
ORDER BY isPreferred DESC, name ASC 
LIMIT 0,20
```

The result is

```
geonameid   name
78910   Milan
12345   New York City
34542   Tampere
```

But I expect

```
geonameid   name
78910   Milano
12345   New York
34542   Tampere
71132   Sanaa
```

Any help?

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE geoname (
  geonameid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  country CHAR(2),
  fcode VARCHAR(5));
  
CREATE TABLE alternatename (
  id_name INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  geonameid INT(11),
  lang CHAR(2),
  name VARCHAR(250),
  isPreferred TINYINT(1) NULL); 
  
INSERT INTO geoname (geonameid,country,fcode) VALUES 
("12345","US","PPL"), 
("78910","IT","PPL"), 
("34542","FI","PPL"),
("5","IR","PPL"),
("71132","YE","ADM1");
 
INSERT INTO alternatename (geonameid,lang,name,isPreferred) VALUES 
("12345","en","New York City",NULL),
("12345","en","Big Apple",NULL),
("12345","en","New York",1),
("12345","it","La Grande Mela",NULL),
("12345","it","New York",1),
("12345","ru","New York",1),
("78910","en","Milan",1),
("78910","it","Milano",1),
("34542","en","Tampere",NULL),
("5","fa","Yekāhī",NULL),
("71132","ar","صنعاء",NULL),
("71132","fr","Muhafadat Sanaa",NULL),
("71132",NULL,"Sanaa",NULL);
```

----- EDIT WITH FINAL QUERIES THANKS TO REPLIES ----

```
SELECT 
geonameid
FROM geoname
WHERE fcode='PPL'
LIMIT 0,10
```

output -->  12345,78910,34542

```
SELECT 
geonameid, 
COALESCE( 
MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'it' and isPreferred=1 THEN name END), 
MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'it' THEN name END), 
MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'en' and isPreferred=1 THEN name END),  
MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'en' THEN name END), 
MAX(name) ) as name 
FROM alternatename a 
WHERE geonameid IN (12345,78910,34542) 
GROUP BY geonameid 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: mysql version is 8.0.27

Comment: Why do you expect 'Sanaa' in the result. The row with 71132 is eliminated by fcode =  'PPL'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using conditional aggregation :

```sql
SELECT
  g.geonameid,
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'it' THEN name END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang = 'en' THEN name END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.lang IS NULL THEN name END)
  ) as name
FROM
  geoname g
  LEFT JOIN alternatename a ON g.geonameid = a.geonameid AND (a.lang = 'it' OR a.lang = 'en' OR a.lang IS NULL)
WHERE
  a.name IS NOT NULL
  AND g.fcode = 'PPL'
GROUP BY
  g.geonameid 
ORDER BY
  a.isPreferred DESC,
  a.name ASC 
LIMIT 0,20
```

Output :

| geonameid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 78910 | Milano |
| 12345 | New York |
| 71132 | Sanaa |
| 34542 | Tampere |

(I assumed `71132` to be also `PPL`, else "Sanaa" would not be part of the results as stated by lukas.j in the comments).

Also in your expected results I guess "Sanaa" should appear before "Tampere" (alphabetical order).

Another solution would be to use subqueries, or to join multiple times on the `alternatename` table (for each language you want to consider in the order by), then still use `coalesce` to get first non-null retrieved values.

Comment: I accept this as solution as it is the one that helped me to find a way.
I will manage with a double query, the first on geoname and the second on alternatename with a WHERE geonameid IN (....,....,...). I edit my question with the final query.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 you can use a lateral join that gets the top name record for each location according to your sort order.

```
SELECT g.geonameid,
       a.name 
       FROM geoname g 
            JOIN LATERAL (SELECT a.name
                                 FROM alternatename a
                                 WHERE g.geonameid = a.geonameid
                                       AND a.lang IN ('it',
                                                      'en')
                                        OR a.lang IS NULL
                                 ORDER BY a.lang DESC,
                                          coalesce(a.ispreferred, 0) DESC
                                 LIMIT 1) a
       WHERE g.fcode = 'PPL'
       LIMIT 0,
             20;
```

Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Also note that `= NULL` is never true as `NULL` isn't equal to anything, even `NULL`. Use `IS NULL` to check if a value is `NULL.

Comment: Didn't know JOIN LATERAL.  I added ORDER BY a.alternateName ASC before the last LIMIT since I need names ordered ASC. The query works... but it's really really slow, even if I'm using index for all fields. Consider that the two tables have millions of rows. Any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

An option for MySQL 8+ is using `ROW_NUMBER()`, in your sample scripts, there is no index on `alternatename.geonameid`, better add one.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4diFoUVXRGdeZtVFXQPj1L/1)

```
WITH selection AS (
  SELECT 
    g.geonameid, 
    a.name, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.geonameid ORDER BY a.lang DESC, COALESCE(a.isPreferred, 0) DESC) name_order
  FROM geoname g
  LEFT JOIN alternatename a ON g.geonameid = a.geonameid AND ( a.lang IN ( 'it', 'en' ) OR a.lang IS NULL )
)
SELECT geonameid, name
FROM selection
WHERE name_order = 1
;
```

Comment: In this case, if I remove AND g.geonameid = 12345 I receive one record. My goal is to have multiple records as output

Comment: @Luca if you need to return multiple `geonameid`, it needs to partition by g.geonameid, e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.geonameid ORDER BY ... ` , `LIMIT 0, 20` could also be problem, you might want to remove it and add it to outer select